# Rails: execute JavaScript after a file form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I've been struggling with this for days. I need to be able to **execute JavaScript code after a file form is submitted** so I can do something with that file.

These are the approachs that I've already tried:

### 1) Call js.erb file through controller's action

routes.rb:

```
post 'workflows/:id/upload', to: 'workflows#upload_files', as: 'workflows_upload_files', defaults: { :format => 'js' }
```

controller (empty):

```
def upload_files
end
```

upload_files.js.erb:

```
console.log('Some log');
```

form:

```
<%= form_for(:printing_file, remote: true, html: { id: 'upload-form'}, url: workspace_workflows_upload_files_path(@workspace, workflow)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true, name: 'workflow[printing_files][]', class: "printing-file-upload-field", onchange: "this.form.submit()" %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know why, but this produces a cross-origin error. When I solve it adding `protect_from_forgery except: :upload_files` then the js code is being rendered as plain text but not evaluated.

I've tried with adding this code on `application.js` but it didn't worked (a solution proposed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20628013/4644486)):

```
 $.ajaxSetup({  
    'beforeSend': function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');}  
 });
```

### 2) Handle input field change event

I've also tried the solution on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/4644486):

```
$(".printing-file-upload-field").change(function(){
  console.log(this.files);
});
```

The result: the event is fired, but I only got `undefined`.

### 3) Handle form complete event

I've also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543243/4644486).

```
$("#upload-form").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
  console.log('The form was submitted!');
});
```

The result: the event isn't triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used a variant of the 2nd option: handle the input field change event.

The problem was that I was submitting the form, so I changed `onchange='this.form.submit()'` for `onchange='readInputFile(this)'` and it worked. Then I added this code to manipulate the file:

```
readInputFile = function(input_file_field) {
    if (input_file_field.files && input_file_field.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            doSomethingWithTheFile(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input_file_field.files[0]);
    }
}
```

I also discovered that in the 3rd option the event wasn't triggered because it doesn't trigger when you submit the form "manually" with `this.form.submit()`.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try removing remote: true from the form_for ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-ajax

Comment: Same problem, JS code is rendered as plain text and not evaluated.

Comment: btw are you using turbolinks on this app ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Turbolinks.